# Jenkins - Master and Slave asynchronous

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I've installed a master jenkins instance and 2 slave nodes.
Both slaves are not synchronous with the master. Sometimes it shows that the slaves are 2 days or 1 hour in the future, sometimes it shows that time on slaves is behind the master - it seems to randomize.
Because of this some selenium tests or builds or other jobs doesn't work correctly anymore. The problem occurred suddenly and it doesn't matter which version of jenkins has been installed.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this problem?

Thank you very much.
Cheers
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to explain why the time difference would vary abruptly between the two machines. I assume you are referring to the information given by the `http://jenkins.mydomain/computer/` url.

Normally you want to keep your machines in time sync, and enable [NTP clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) on each host, each pointing to the same set of NTP servers, either internal to your organization (if that is available), or the standard free NTP services available on the web.

Do you have this setup already and see abrupt time variations? If so, review your list of NTP services and make sure to use reliable ones and also the same list, it should help. Maybe narrow it down to just one service and then expand if need be.